# A place nearby, or a nearby place?

Tags: sentence-construction

What's the correct order in the following context? A place nearby,  or a nearby place?

> a) "Please,  recommend me on a **place nearby** where I can buy socks…"
>
> b) "Please,  recommend me on a **nearby place** where I can buy socks…"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nearby), **nearby** can be either an adverb or an adjective.

in example b), **nearby** is before the noun it modifies: this the correct place for an adjective. This sentence is therefore correct.

In example a), **nearby** is at the end of the clause: this is the correct position when using **nearby** as an adverb, but what verb does it modify? It doesn't make sense for it to modify **recommend**. You will definitely hear people saying things like this, but it is not grammatically correct.

Here is an example of a correct usage as an adverb: it modifies the verb **is**.

> If there's a café nearby, we could stop for a snack.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the correct order in the following context? A place nearby, or a nearby place?
>
> a) "Please, recommend me on a place nearby where I can buy socks…"
>
> b) "Please, recommend me on a nearby place where I can buy socks…"

---

I would suggest that both sentences need a little attention.

"please recommend" sounds more like an instruction that a request, albeit a polite one, by modern day standards. The can you after the please softens the request.

a) "Please, can you recommend a place (nearby, where) I can buy socks…?"

in this instance a place means any place or some place, which becomes

"Please, can you recommend someplace I can buy socks…" so to confirm that the place should be nearby we would say

> a) **"Please, can you recommend someplace near, where I can buy socks…?"**
>
> **someplace adverb**: somewhere:
>
> **place noun** (AREA) an area, town, building, etc.:
>
> **near adverb, preposition**; not far away in distance:
>
> b) **"Please, can you recommend a nearby place where I can buy socks…?"**

so I would suggest that your second sentence is the nearest if you are to use the word nearby. However you could say,

C) **"Is there anywhere around here that sells socks…?"**

[All references Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/someplace)